# What is the minimum number of push operation in reversing A B C D in stack?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, stack, queue, push

I Have coded to reverse the ABCD string with using push and pop operation in Javascript

```js
var count = 0;
function reverse(str) {
    let stack = [];
    // push letter into stack
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        stack.push(str[i]);
        count++
    }
    // pop letter from the stack
    let reverseStr = '';
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        reverseStr += stack.pop();
    }
    return reverseStr;
}

console.log(reverse("ABCD") + count);
```

What is the minimum number of push operation in reversing ABCD?

Comment: Surely the minimum amount of push operations is three - leave `D` first, then push the other three behind it in reverse order. Although, technically you can do it with zero pushes as well. I'm not talking about an alternative code that avoids push but still accomplishes the same task - you can just slightly alter your code and never call push. It will not reverse the array but it *is* a lower number of operations. You never specified that the reversing should be *successful* or *correct*.

Comment: You can do it with three push operation , taking the last entry inside the array first and then pushing  the other three. This operation can be performed with single loop as well if we just loop reversely . Moreover it can also be accomplished without a loop as well .  str.split('').reverse().join('')

Comment: if i use single stack what will be the output of A B C D sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **maximum** number should be either 3 or 4 depending on how you do it.  Firstly, you should be using unshift() rather than push() as you really only need to *push* a character into the *front* of the array.  So:

```js
let count;
function reverse(str) {
    count = 0;
    let stack = [];
    // push letter into stack
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        stack.unshift(str[i]);
        count++
    }
    return stack.join("");
}

let stringA = "ABCD";

console.log(stringA + " => " + reverse(stringA) + ": " + count);
```

However, as others have suggested, you could just **move** letters, going backwards from the one before the final character, and shifting them to the end:

```js
let count;

function reverse2(str) {
  count = 0;
  let str2 = str.split("");
  let sLength = str2.length;
  for (let i = (sLength - 2); i >= 0; i--) {
    let s = str2.splice(i, 1).toString();
    str2.push(s);
      count++
  }
  return str2.join("");
}
let stringB = "ABCD";

console.log(stringB + " => " + reverse2(stringB) + ": " + count);
```

In both cases, you *could* check for matching consecutive characters - eg, in **good**, you have two o's.  But that would complicate things as you would be continually checking for this.

Answer (score 0):

you don't even need the push operations if you are using JS `str.split('').reverse().join('')` and by the way it only takes 3 push operations.

Comment: While correct, the op was not wanting to solve it this way, but see how few times they could do it but adding / removing from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum number of Push Operation is equal to length of string as stack follows Last In First Out Order.